# Unable to Run Code First Seed Method - Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am unable to insert records to a table, receiving the error Sequence contains more than one element.
The Entity that I want to add inherits from another table in a Table Per Hierachy (TPH) relationship like to.

```
public abstract class Reward
    {
        public int RewardId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Retailer")]
        public int RetailerId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Reward Name")]
        public string RewardName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }


        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Boolean Status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Reward Type")]
        public Enums.RewardType RewardType { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Customer> EnrolledCustomers { get; set; }
        public virtual Retailer BusinessName { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, this Entity extends the above Entity like so

```
  public class CashReward : Reward
    {

        [Display(Name = "Default Cash Value")]
        public double DefaultCashValue { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "X Value - Amount Spent")]
        public decimal XAmountSpent { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Y Value - Amount Earned")]
        public decimal YAmountEarned { get; set; }

    }
```

From this above, Entity Framework created a Reward Table like so (Please note that two other classes extend the Reward class but I am focused only on the Cash Reward Class/Entity)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rewards] (
    [RewardId]                   INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RetailerId]                 INT             NOT NULL,
    [RewardName]                 NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [StartDate]                  DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [EndDate]                    DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [Description]                NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [Status]                     BIT             NOT NULL,
    [RewardType]                 INT             NOT NULL,
    [DefaultCashValue]           FLOAT (53)      NULL,
    [XAmountSpent]               DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
    [YAmountEarned]              DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
    [DefaultValue]               INT             NULL,
    [CurrentNumberOfTransaction] INT             NULL,
    [TargetNumberOfTransaction]  INT             NULL,
    [GetYFree]                   INT             NULL,
    [DefaultPointsValue]         BIGINT          NULL,
    [XAmountSpent1]              DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
    [YPointsEarned]              BIGINT          NULL,
    [Discriminator]              NVARCHAR (128)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Rewards] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RewardId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Rewards_dbo.Retailers_RetailerId] FOREIGN KEY ([RetailerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Retailers] ([RetailerId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I am trying to add two records of type CashReward using EF Code First Seed method like so:

```
var cashRewards = new List<Reward>
            {
                new CashReward
                {
                   RetailerId = retailers.Single( i => i.BusinessName == "Prime Lending").RetailerId,
                   RewardName = "October Fest Bonanza",
                   StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                   EndDate  = DateTime.Parse("12/23/2014"),
                   Description = "Best reward for the month of October",
                   Status = true,
                   RewardType = Enums.RewardType.CashReward,
                   DefaultCashValue = 2,
                   XAmountSpent = 20,
                   YAmountEarned = 1                 
              },

                new CashReward
                {
                   RetailerId = retailers.Single( i => i.BusinessName == "Mike Liquor Store").RetailerId,
                   RewardName = "Loyal Customer Reward",
                   StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                   EndDate  = DateTime.Parse("2/9/2014"),
                   Description = "Hope you enjoy the best reward for the month of October",
                   Status = true,
                   RewardType = Enums.RewardType.CashReward,
                   DefaultCashValue = 5,
                   XAmountSpent = 40,
                   YAmountEarned = 5                 
              },

            };

            cashRewards.ForEach(r => context.Reward.AddOrUpdate(p => p.RewardName, r));
            context.SaveChanges();
```

And I am getting error message

Running Seed method.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](DbSet`1 set, IEnumerable`1 identifyingProperties, InternalSet`1 internalSet, TEntity[] entities)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate[TEntity](IDbSet`1 set, Expression`1 identifierExpression, TEntity[] entities)
   at ValueCard.Web.Migrations.Configuration.<>c__DisplayClass22.<Seed>b__1a(Reward r) in \Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 113
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
```

Please help of point me to the right direction. Thanks for your time

Comment: Sounds like Mike's got more than one liquor store in there...

Comment: I had a similar problem, exact same error.  Turns out I was MapToStoredProcedure in my FluentAPI and that was causing the problem.  So I just went back to table operations by removing it till I figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

The stack trace shows that the exception comes from

```
cashRewards.ForEach(r => context.Reward.AddOrUpdate(p => p.RewardName, r));
```

And the exception is thrown while executing `AddOrUpdate`. This is because `AddOrUpdate` expects an expression that uniquely identifies the object of which is has to decide whether it should be added or updated. This simply means you've got more than one `CashReward` in the database with the names you try to add.

BTW, you can also do

```
context.Reward.AddOrUpdate(p => p.RewardName, cashRewards.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried all the suggestions however this appears to be a bug with EF6/ASP.Net MVC5/ VS 2013. It works for me in VS 2012 and EF 5 so I have switched back to VS 2012 I will try VS 2013 later when.

Comment: OMG that's bad news! Is is submitted as a bug [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you may have a duplicate business name in your query. Try replacing your call `.Single` with `.FirstOrDefault`

`FirstOrDefault` will return the first matching element and `null` if none is found.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have changed to use FirstOrDefault and I still get the same error.